# Regex Notepad++ Del all except IP

Tags: regex, notepad++

Have a text file, each line contains an IP address with useless info. Want to delete useless info around the IP.

Each line looks like:

```
%BER-1-887373: Group <Connect> User <gacan> IP <72.34.184.200> No IPv6 address available
```

Need the IP Address only

The < > surround the IP and need to delete those as well.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Can you share a few samples for some of the lines?

Comment: Here is a sample of one of the lines, not an actual IP of course..

%BER-1-887373: Group <Connect> User <gacan> IP <72.34.184.200> No IPv6 address available

Comment: @planejane Can you update your question with this sample line. It can get missed out if is there in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any other groups of numbers separated by periods and enclosed in `<...>`, you can find:

```
.*<(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})>.*
```

and replace with

```
$1
```

This doesn't validate the IP address; it just finds 4 groups of 1-3 numbers inside `<...>` and with periods between groups.

Given your sample text, this would reduce this line

```
%BER-1-887373: Group <Connect> User <gacan> IP <72.34.184.200>
```

to just `72.34.184.200`.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pU2tL0/2)

## Explanation:

- `.*` - match any character zero or more times (anything from the start of the line to the `<`)
- `<` - match a literal character `<`
- `(` - start a capturing group so we can use it in the replacement

  - `\d{1,3}` - match 1 to 3 digits
  - `(?:` - start a non-capturing group

    - `\.` - match a literal `.`
    - `\d{1,3}` - match 1-3 digits
  - `)` - end the non-capturing group
  - `{3}` - repeat the non-capturing group 3 times (to give us a total of 4 groups of digits, with 3 periods in between them)
- `)` - end the capturing group
- `>` - match a literal `>`
- `.*` - match any character zero or more times (the rest of the line)

The replacement `$1` means to use the first capturing group (the part between `(` and `)`), which in this case is the IP address. (`$0` would be all matched text, which in this case is the entire line).

Comment: could you walk me through what each character in the solution is doing for learning purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Do a find replace:

- **Find what:** `.*?(\d{1,3}((.\d{1,3}){3})).*`
- **Replace whith:** `\1`
- select **Regular Expression**
- Hit Replace all

The pattern is not perfect as it does not limit the range of the valid numbers (e.g. 999.999.999.99 will be matched too).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this deleted everything and left behind the 1-887373 only

Comment: Did you select in the lower left: Regular Expression and have `. matches newline` unchecked?

Comment: I did have it unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Regex tend to be complicated at times and there is a good chance you get it wrong. If all the lines are supposed to be in the specified format i.e. three words before IP and two words following it, I would use Macros.
Let's say the example is:

```
abc xyz xxxx <127.23.32.120> xxx xyz
```

1. I would bring the cursor to the end of the first line.
2. Press the `record marco` button (red button at the top)
3. Press Ctrl + Bksp twice. This will delete the xyz and xxx characters.
4. Press Bksp twice: This deletes the space and `>` characters
5. Press Ctrl + Left Arrow 7 times. This will move the cursor at the beginning of the IP
6. Press Ctrl + Bksp 4 times. This will delete the other useless text and leave you just with the IP in the first line.
7. Press Down Arrow followed by the `End` button to move to the end of the next line
8. Stop recording the macro.
9. Play the marco until the end of the file.

Comment: Great idea, however, this would have worked if each of the lines were the exact same length. In other words, some lines have more useless info than others.  Many thanks, I learned how to use macros!